# How do I include a request scoped provider which needs an injected request in via an imported module

Tags: nestjs

We are building up a mono-repo of microservices, and want to have some shared libraries which we import into various services.

Right now I am trying to build up a shared module which will have a provider which needs access to the request. Here is an example:

```
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common'
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core'
import { Request } from 'express'
import { APILogger } from '@freebird/logger'
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda'

export interface IAPIGatewayRequest extends Request {
  apiGateway?: {
    event?: APIGatewayProxyEvent
    context?: Context
  }
}

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class RequestLogger extends APILogger {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) request: IAPIGatewayRequest) {
    if (!request.apiGateway || !request.apiGateway.event || !request.apiGateway.context) {
      throw new Error(
        'You are trying to use the API Gateway logger without having used the aws-serverless-express middleware',
      )
    }

    super(request.apiGateway.event, request.apiGateway.context)
  }
}
```

I have been trying to bundle this as a module like so:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RequestLogger } from './logger'

@Module({
  providers: [RequestLogger],
  exports: [RequestLogger],
})
export class LambdaModule {}
```

And then import it into the main service module like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AppController } from './app.controller'
import { AppService } from './app.service'
import { LambdaModule } from '@freebird/nest-lambda'

@Module({
  imports: [LambdaModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However, when I do this I get an error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RequestLogger (?). Please make
>   sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AppModule
>   context.

But when I pull the RequestLogger provider into the service module, and include it like this I get no errors:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AppController } from './app.controller'
import { AppService } from './app.service'
import { RequestLogger } from './logger'

@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, RequestLogger],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. In my case I had slightly different requirements between my library package and the service package. So different versions of nest were in play. This apparently causes conflicts.